# How to get base64 only text in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular file upload component, where I want to get the base64 and save it. So far it works, but my base64 starts like this:

"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk/N8KM......."

is there anyway to only get the code and not the data:application/pdf;base64 etc.

Here is my code:

```
  uploadFile(files: FileList | null): void {
      if(files){
        const file = files.item(0)
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onload = () => {
        this.documentsArray.push({documentType: this.form.controls.dokumentType.value, fileBase64: reader.result,fileName: file.name})
        console.log(this.documentsArray)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Operations involving creating documents on fly by reading FileData often involves encoding-type. The return type for you, in the given example, is just a string & so you can apply string operations like substring to remove the unwanted part.

Comment: Do you maybe have an example I never did it? Another question is, if I save it in my database in the form how it is now, would it still work? could I send this from my backend and make it downloadable? I mean if it starts like this:
"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk/N8KM......."

Comment: It should work and to download file, you can try `window.open(this.base64Response, '_blank');` where `this.base64Response="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk/N8KM......."`

Comment: Thanks, another question, is there anyway to convert base64 to string? or is it initially a string already? I tried toString method but it did not work

Comment: It should be string already. And this should work: `const test = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk/N8KM"; test.substring(test.indexOf(',') + 1);`

Comment: sadly I am not getting the substring method. I am using reader.result to return the base64. How should I do it then?

Comment: `window.open(reader.result as any, '_blank');` should do the trick